# What does it mean to "stock the campfire"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I heard in a movie description:

> Worm-like grubs writhe in a pot, as Edy **stocks the campfire** with a stick.

The scene shows a man, Edy, using a stick to stir a campfire. Does the verb **stock** have the meaning of "stir"? Or does it refer to a different action? I am putting the [audio clip here](https://clyp.it/p4iybj5c) for reference (uploaded to Clyp, an audio sharing site).

Comment: Whoever wrote that probably meant *stokes* the campfire. I can't see how *stocks* would work there.

Comment: @Robusto That makes perfect sense. I think you just answered my question.

Comment: The speaker in the audio clip says **stokes** not **stocks**.  To "stoke" can mean to rearrange the fuel in a fire to make it burn with greater heat.  For example, you can push the sticks in a campfire together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an error.

The intended word was probably "stoke" which means "to add fuel to a fire", or "to stir a fire with a poker or stick so it burns well". [Stoke](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stoke)

Comment: I don't think that **stoke** was used in error. It can also mean ["to poke or stir up (a fire, flames, etc.)"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoke), in which case stoking with a stick makes perfect sense.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll edit to reflect that.